Is there a ''mathematical'' reason for the distinction of black/white keys on a piano or is there only a cultural reason?
This question can be found in different forms on the internet and this website. Unfortunately, I am not satisfied with the given answers: They are partly even different from another. So please let me ask again and point out more specifically, where my problem is.
I have a (for me fairly satisfying) reason, why there are 12 notes in an octave on the piano
C, C#, D, D#, E, F, F#, G, G#, A, A#, H, (C)
(and it is not important for this reason if they are tuned in equal temperament or whatsoever): The Pythagorean method of stacking perfect fifth from the root note C ends up (after rescaling by 1/2^n in order to land again in the given octave) at the top C (i.e. a multiple of 2) approximately with 12 iterations. The 'natural choice' of the perfect fifth here is from the lowest non-trivial position in the harmonic series. Alright.
But what about the 7 white keys
C, D, E, F, G, A, H, (C)
in an octave on the piano? Is there a non-cultural reason for taking these notes of the above-mentioned 12-tone scale?

For example, it could be reasonable to take the first notes of the Pythagorean stacking-fifth-system from above but they are
C, G, D, A, E, H
and then comes F# which is not of the wanted form. For the last step, one could go a perfect fifth down from the root note C to obtain F. This is the same a starting to stack fifths from F on. But what is a reason to start with F instead of C? Why not start at B for example? Is there a non-cultural reason?
The first notes of the harmonic series from C are (approximately) C, G, E, ~B, D, ~F, but there is no A in sight, only much later. So this does not seem convincing for me either.
The harmonic series from C contains the C-major chord C-G-E very early, and in particular the major third E of C. So is there a way to stack major thirds to obtain the C major scale? Well: C, E, G#. No, this does not work. Even a combination of fifth and thirds does not yield the desired scale.
As already mentioned, the harmonic series contains a major chord on the fundamental very early. In fact all the desired seven notes are in the major chords on C (C, E, G) on G (G, H, D) and F (F, A, C). Starting from C, G is a fifth above and F a fifth below (or a fifth from F to C). This is probably very natural. Could this be the reason?


Is there conceptual (non-cultural) reason for the white keys on the piano?

Please let me clarify that I do not want to diminish a 'cultural reason' (i.e. something like: it is like this because it developed by chance through music history) below a conceptual one.

Search the site for some of the posts on why the keyboard layout is as it is. Combination of math and history.

“it could be reasonable to take the first notes of the Pythagorean stacking-fifth-system from above but they are C, G, D, A, E, H and then comes F#”. Not if you start on F. Starting on F gives you F C G D A E B(H in the German system). The white keys are the first seven pitch classes derived from going up in fifths from F, not from C.

@ToddWilcox, yes, this is what I've wrote as well but why then start with F and not with B (the international notation is Bb), further down a fifth?

@mrpotato Seems like a separate question, but there has to be a starting note. Any note is a good as any other to start on. Why not start on F? It doesn’t really matter. As far as I can see, your first bullet point is incorrect. The white keys do form a cycle of stacked 5ths.

@ToddWilcox, OK, I meant cycle of stacked 5ths starting from C. But this seems to be not accepted by everybody as the reason for the white keys: See for example the comment of phoog below the top answer. I am confused.

C was not the default home note when the natural notes of western music were developed, so there’s no reason to expect the notes of the whites keys were derived from C in any way. That’s the point I was trying to make. The idea that F is not easily derived from C makes sense because C was not as important for most of the history of western music.

@ToddWilcox indeed, the whole overtone series idea was not particularly prevalent for much of that time.  Pythagoras didn't have much use for any ratio other than 3:2, and during the middle ages, when Pythagorean tuning prevailed, the major third was a dissonant interval.

The closest I've found to a mathematical reason for why the black notes are the ones assigned is that people have historically disagreed on the precise pitches of the black notes a lot more. (See split black notes on ancient keyboards for more info.)

It is a musical reason.
The white keys form the tones of the diatonic gamut of pitches, lettered A-G.
The black keys are the half steps between the white keys separated by whole steps.
You can think of the interaction/relationship of the white and black keys in two important ways:

The black keys allow chromatic inflection both melodic and harmonic to the diatonic tones.
With the combination of white and black keys the diatonic gamut can be transposed to any of the 12 chromatic steps.

That begs the question "why a diatonic gamut?"
That isn't the OP's main question, but it might as well be addressed.
The question to that is mostly cultural, but depending on how you look at it, a wide range of cultures need to be included. Also, it is partly acoustical. In a nutshell the overtone series supports the acoustical notion that a root position major triad is resonant and therefore preferred by people. By extension the octave and the perfect fifth a preferred intervals. From a starting pitch jumping up four perfect fifths yields tones for a pentatonic scale and two more jumps yields the diatonic gamut of seven tones. Those scales can be viewed as a kind of manifestation of an acoustic fundamental (the perfect fifth) which is the reason for their cultural significance.

I do not understand your last paragraph about the diatonic scale derived from perfect fifths. As I pointed out above, this yields only F# as the 7th tone, not F.

@mrpotato So you derive seven pitch classes from C and get an F sharp and then play G to G and you’ve still got a major scale. Or, put another way, we can guess the pitches were derived from F leading to B natural (H) a half step below C and therefore the major scale is C to C and F to F is Lydian.

@ToddWilcox As I've written, this is clear to me, but I don't understand why one starts at F and not at C itself.

@mrpotato because the choice of white keys was not made as a result of stacking fifths.  Also note that the overtone series does not contain E very early as the result of stacking Pythagorean fifths; that E isn't the fifth harmonic; it is the eighty-first.

@phoog I am confused about yout comment on E: I define it as the major third from C. Then it is the 5th harmonic. Or am I wrong?

@mrpotato, the thing about stacked fifths says nothing about the arrangement of the tones into particular octaves, scales, etc. or treating any one as tonic, it just provides a collection of pitch classes and a base for tonality.

You don't start with F, or C, or any other tone. The starting point is a diatonic gamut of seven tones, along with the importance of a root position major triad, and that is the basis of tonality. From there you have centuries of different musical styles implementing that tonal base.

@mrpotato the E that is the fifth harmonic is related to C by a ratio of 5:4.  The E that one obtains by stacking Pythagorean fifths is related to C by a ratio of 81:64.  But I rather suspect that people were playing and singing tunes for millennia before Pythagoras worked out the importance of the fifth.  I'm pretty sure this is a case of theory developing to describe practice.  So the whole "derivation" of the scale is an ex post facto explanation, not a procedure to generate music from first principles.
